# Firebase event "<user> is writing..." like WhatsApp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any manner to clone the whatsapp event "**[user] is writing...**" in Firebase events?

I have reading about the Firebase events in https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/ but I've not found anything about the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing immediately available with Firebase, although it is a good piece to help solve this problem. What platform you are targeting? (Web, Android, iOS, etc).

Comment: Hello funador. I'm using Web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote such a typing indicator a while ago.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<your-app>.firebaseio.com');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var typers = document.getElementById('typers');
var uid = Date.now(); // generate a fake user id
var timer;

// attach a listener that display all people current typing in a list
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  typers.innerText = '';
  snapshot.forEach(function(typer) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = typer.key();
    typers.appendChild(li);
  });
});

// whenever the content of the textarea changes
input.addEventListener('input',function(e) {
  // mark this user a "typing"
  ref.child(uid).set(true);
  // if we're counting down, stop the timer
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  // remove this user in 2 seconds
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    ref.child(uid).remove();
  }, 2000);
});
```

To see it in action, have a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cociyi/edit?html,js,output).
The [tweet where I announced it](https://twitter.com/puf/status/661189216940851201).

Answer (score 2):

You can set a flag in the chat information

ex:

`{ "chat1 : 
    {
      "name: "Jon", 
      "isWriting" : true
     }
"}`

When sending a message to change the boolean value to "false" set a time to change the boolean value to false if no more connection to the Internet.

Comment: Thanks Dennes. Your response is very valued too.