# Reactjs - Firebase : Cancel Old Requests

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to **Firebase Realtime Database**, and i'm trying to implement a search field that allow users to search for other users and view their profiles.
**The Problem Is:**
I want to make the search realTime(on each input change).but whenever a new request's sent, the old request is still working in the backend which's causing unexpected behavior,i've wrapped this functionality in a useEffect Hook,old sideEffects has to be cleaned up to make the query results predictable,how can i abort the previous request.
**useSearchOwner Custom Hook:**

```
const useSearchOwner = () => {
    const [{ SearchValue, SearchResult, Search }, dispatch] = useReducer(
        reducer,
        {
            SearchValue: "",
            SearchResult: "",
            Search: false,
        }
    );
    const isFirstRender = useRef(true);
    const onChangeHandler = (e) =>
        dispatch({
            type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_SEARCH_VALUE,
            payload: { searchValue: e.target.value },
        });
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isFirstRender.current) {
            isFirstRender.current = false;
            return;
        }

        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.START_SEARCHING });
        const DispatchQueryByResult = async () => {
            const ArrayOfOwners = await FirebaseUtilityInstance.SearchOwnerResult(
                SearchValue
            );

            dispatch({
                type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_SEARCH_RESULT,
                payload: { searchResult: ArrayOfOwners },
            });
            dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.STOP_SEARCHING });
            return () => {
                FirebaseUtilityInstance.SearchOwnerCleanup();
            };
        };
        DispatchQueryByResult();
    }, [SearchValue]);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(SearchResult);
    }, [SearchResult]);
    return {
        onChangeHandler: onChangeHandler,
        Query: SearchValue,
        QueryResult: SearchResult,
        isSearching: Search,
    };
};
```

**Firebase Method To Do Query:**

```
SearchOwnerResult = async (Query) => {
        const { firstName, lastName } = getFirstNameAndLastName(Query);
        let ArrayOfOwners = [];
        await this.Database()
            .ref("users")
            .orderByChild("UserType")
            .equalTo("owner")
            .once("value", (snapshot) => {
                const OwnersContainer = snapshot.val();
                const keys = Object.keys(OwnersContainer);
                for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    const CurrentOwner = OwnersContainer[keys[i]];
                    if (
                        CurrentOwner.FirstName === firstName ||
                        CurrentOwner.LastName === lastName
                    ) {
                        ArrayOfOwners.push(OwnersContainer[keys[i]]);
                    }
                }
            });
        return ArrayOfOwners;
    };
```

Comment: Instead of trying to search on each input change and trying to cancel pending requests perhaps it makes more sense to not send so many bad requests to begin with. Debounce the onChange handler so requests are only made when user stops typing for some small duration.

Comment: Thought of that actually like adding a Timeout for seconds before fetching.thank you very much!

Comment: What you're looking for is common referred to as a debounce. For an example implementation (used for a "typing..." indicator"), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130007/firebase-event-user-is-writing-like-whatsapp

Comment: Thank you very much! I’ll check it out,i’ll probably go with what @Drew Reese Suggested!